# Why is my upload / Select media library button empty?

Tags: media-library

The button seems to exist but the content of the button is empty.

I have tried:

- Disabling all the plugins
- Downloading again wordpress and overwriting wp-includes and wp-admin with the original files.
- Clearing the Browser cache
- Clearing the Wordpress cache

Still doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that you can't defer the javascript loading on the whole site or it will mess up some contents on the backend.
I have to check if the page is the backend or the frontend and block the function just for backend with `if (!(is_admin() ))`.

```
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        // return "$url' defer ";
        return "$url' defer onload='";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```